# How to add parameter to query in Azure Data Factory Lookup against Table Storage

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory

I am trying to create a pipeline in ADF to extract data from data in a Table Storage where the value matches a parameter.

If I hard code the value, the query runs, and I can see data

Query:

```
RowKey eq 'Brand' and Value eq 'Brand1'
```

I have added a parameter called brand.

I would expect the following to work:

Query:

```
RowKey eq 'Brand' and Value eq @pipeline().parameters.brand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this expression:

```
RowKey eq 'Brand' and Value eq '@{pipeline().parameters.brand}'
```

In this way, ADF will parse the parameter into a string.

---

I created a simple test for this

```
RowKey eq '@{pipeline().parameters.RowKeyStr}'
```

Type in the expression in the "Query" field:
[image]

[image]